# Oauth Client creation User_controller ERROR Rails 'fitgem'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, oauth-2.0, client, fitbit

I'm trying to let my user make GET requests to the Fitbit API. Currently the user has all of their tokens, but I'm struggling to create a client.

User_controller.rb

```
def show
@user = User.find(params[:id])
if (@user.device != nil)
  p "PRINTING DEVICES"
  p @user.device
  @device = @user.device

  @client = Fitgem::Client.new(
    :consumer_key => 'b4aacb5c2c8c43e2a6873877cd2ad9b1',
    :consumer_secret => '88bd78fc86d84d6c9aa7b1c0b8d4511f',
    :token => @device.oauth_token,
    :secret => @device.oauth_token_secret
  )
end
end
```

The error I am receiving is:

```
        /Users/Marcus/Sites/Rails/rails_projects/BattleOfTheBands/app/controllers/users_controller.rb:        16: syntax error, unexpected tASSOC, expecting ')'
    :consumer_key => 'b4b1',
                    ^
    /Users/Marcus/Sites/Rails/rails_projects/BattleOfTheBands/app/controllers/users_controller.rb:16: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting keyword_end
    /Users/Marcus/Sites/Rails/rails_projects/BattleOfTheBands/app/controllers/users_controller.rb:17: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting keyword_end
    /Users/Marcus/Sites/Rails/rails_projects/BattleOfTheBands/app/controllers/users_controller.rb:19: syntax error, unexpected tASSOC, expecting tCOLON2 or '[' or '.'
    :secret => @device.oauth_token_secret
              ^
    /Users/Marcus/Sites/Rails/rails_projects/BattleOfTheBands/app/controllers/users_controller.rb:21: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end
    /Users/Marcus/Sites/Rails/rails_projects/BattleOfTheBands/app/controllers/users_controller.rb:86: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end
```

Comment: You've got some stray punctuation someplace. "expecting ')'" is usually a sign that there's a comma missing in an argument list.